# manipulate numpy arrays in a nested list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to manipulate numpy arrays in a nested list.

I have a nested list, and in each inner list, there are several numpy arrays.

```
a = [
[np.random.normal(0,1,[2,3]), np.random.normal(0,1,[4,5]), np.random.normal(0,1, [9, 10])],
[np.random.normal(0,1,[2,3]), np.random.normal(0,1,[4,5]), np.random.normal(0,1, [9, 10])],
[np.random.normal(0,1,[2,3]), np.random.normal(0,1,[4,5]), np.random.normal(0,1, [9, 10])]
]
```

I want to element-wise compute mean of each of the numpy arrays in each list correspondingly to get a new list `b`, where elements are the mean of the three `np.random.normal(0,1,[2,3])`, the mean of the three `np.random.normal(0,1,[4,5])`, etc.

My initial thought was to write down a for-loop to fetch corresponding arrays and compute mean of them and then add to a list. However, this may be a bit slow when having a large number of such arrays or inner list.

Comment: I'm confused at why you'd have a list formatted like that. Why not have a list in a transposed form to what you have, i.e. have the arrays of the same size in the same sublist?

Comment: And why are you putting Numpy arrays into a 2D list like that, rather than doing it all in a Numpy array, or at least a 1D list of arrays?

Comment: @PM2Ring the arrays are of different size, meaning they cannot be put in a numpy array. However, if he organized it as I have, it would just be a list of numpy arrays instead of a nested Python list.

Comment: As long as the arrays differ in shape there isn't much you can do.  Where shapes match you can 'stack' and perform fast axis wise operations.  Otherwise you are stuck with list iterations.

Comment: @Sebastian Indeed! It should be a list of 3D arrays, with the OP's 2D arrays of the same shape making up the planes of the 3D arrays.

Comment: ytutow, do you want a single mean value for each of your array shapes, so the `b` list contains 3 numbers? Or do you want to find the means of corresponding elements in each column, so that `b` consists of 3 arrays with shapes (2,3), (4,5) & (9,10)?

Comment: @PM2Ring , I suppose it is the second, i.e, b consists of 3 arrays with shapes (2,3), (4,5) & (9,10)

Comment: Hi, @Sebastian sorry for the late, could you elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here's a potential solution:

```
b = [np.mean(row, axis=0) for row in zip(*a)]
```

`zip(*a)` rearranges the nested list into a sensible format, so `row` is the list of equally sized arrays, and `np.mean(row, axis=0)` will get the element-wise mean along the list.

You could also turn each row into a numpy array:

```
b = [np.array(row).mean(axis=0) for row in zip(*a)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!.  `a = [[np.array([2,4]), np.array([4,6])], [np.array([3,5]), np.array([5,7])]]` then `b = [np.mean(row, axis=0) for row in zip(*a)]` gives the exact what supposed: `[array([ 2.5,  4.5]), array([ 4.5,  6.5])]`, I will test it over large scale.